# Combining Strings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-concatenation

I am new to Google Apps Script and am trying to combine a series of strings. I have two strings that need to go before and after an inputted cell.

`if B4 = "string2"`  the result of the following line should be `"string1 string2 string3"` .
`"string1 " + "B4" + " string3"`

String1 and string3 will always be the same so I can set them each to a variable, but I don't know how to concatenate them together. They need to be combined and outputted to a cell in Sheets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add what this looks like in Google Sheets...

=CONCATENATE("string1",'High Level Data'!B4,"string3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are very easy to assemble in JavaScript, simply add them using `+`

From your example :

```
"string1"+" "+string2+" "+"string3"
```

Alternatively you can use the [.concat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) that does exactly the same.