# How to get keys and values of an object into a comma separated string?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }
```

And I would like to return a string that looks like this: `I have 2 apples, 4 eggs, 1 potato`.

I tried the following:

```js
arr = [];
obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 };

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push(`${obj[key]} ${key}`)
    }
}

console.log(arr);

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`I have ${arr[i]}`)
}
```

I don't know how to put them together

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you using the string? Do you know what a string is? Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: First of all you should understand what is array and how it works.

Comment: You are nearly there, use `console.log(\`I have ${arr.join(', ')}.\`)` instead of `for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(\`I have ${arr[i]}\`)
}`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888885/combining-strings? this is pretty much just a combine strings question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You an use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), ES2015 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method like this:

```js
let obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 };

let es6Output = `I have ${Object.keys(obj).map(key => `${obj[key]} ${key}`).join(', ')}`;

// if your browser doesn't support ES2015
let es5Output = "I have " + Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return obj[key] + " " + key
}).join(', ');

console.log(es6Output);
console.log(es5Output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you access every property in your Object using the for in method, then the property is already a string.

Since the value to all your properties are numbers all you'll have to do is convert those values from numbers to strings, see below.

```
obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }    

for (let propa in obj) {
    console.log(`I have ${obj[propa]} ${propa.toString()}`)
}
```

To get it to work in the way you approached, it would be as follows:

```
obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }
let collection = []

for (let propa in obj) {
    collection.push(`I have ${obj[propa]} ${propa}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the properties of an object.
Then you can use the `[]` syntax to get the value of that property.

```js
let obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 };
let message = "I have ";
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
  message += obj[key] + " " + key + ", ";
});
message = message.substring(0, message.length - 2) + ".";
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available to you. Strings in JavaScript can be combined with the `+` operator.

```
console.log("This " + "is a sentence.")
```

To access a key in an object you can use dot notation:

```
console.log({eggs: 4}.eggs)
```

Or bracket notation:

```
console.log({eggs: 4}['eggs'])
```

So to create your string, you can always have the same structure

```
var obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }
console.log('I have ' + obj.apples + ' apples, ' + obj.eggs + ' eggs, ' + obj.potato + ' potato.';
```

Or if order doesn't matter, you can use a loop:

```
var str = 'I have', i = 0, foods = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potatoes: 1 }, count, item;
for(item in foods){
  count = foods[item];
  str = str + (i ? ', ' : (i++ && '')) + count + ' ' + item;
}

console.log(str.replace(', '+ count + ' ' + item, (i > 2 ? ', ' : ' ') + 'and ' + count + ' ' + item + '.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys like so:

```js
var obj = {
    apples: 2,
    eggs: 4,
    potato: 1
};

var string = "I have ";
Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => string += `${obj[prop]} ${prop}, `;);
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this as a solution. where huddlesList list object is like this
{name: "hock", account_folder_id: 354421}

```
this.huddlesList.forEach((e) => {
           this.huddlesListWComma +=e.name;
           this.huddlesListWComma +=', ';
                    })

         this.huddlesListWComma = this.huddlesListWComma.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

this.huddlesListWComma

hock, Ali Amjad - 1, Ali Amjad - 2, Ash Leo, ZXCVBNM1212312, Jane Roe, H11, Assess JV, Test 3/1/21 - Assessment Safari, Ash Leo - 6

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick for you.

```js
let obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }
let string = "I have " + obj.apples.toString() + " apples, " + obj.eggs.toString() + " eggs, " + obj.potato.toString() + " potato.";
console.log(string);
```

Comment: That object was an example, I don't know the key is a string and value is a number, i don't know the content

Comment: Of course, the key will definitely be string, but for the value I added .toString() for it so that it is converted to string now.

Answer (score -1):

this should work for you...

```
   $(function(){
   obj = { apples: 2, eggs: 4, potato: 1 }

      var str = "I Have ";
       $.each(obj, function(index){
        str = str + index + " " + this + " , ";
       });


      alert(str);
       });
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with jQuery

Comment: oh that was my bad

Answer (score -1):

This is how it should work:

```
var food = {apples:2, eggs:4, potato:1};
alert(food["apples"]);
```